# How to extract the same elements across lists in R

Tags: r, list

There are three lists:

```
list1 <- c("123","124","126","131")
list2 <- c("111","123","126","133","159")
list3 <- c("119","120","123","124","126","158")
```

Here, I have to extract the elements that are contained across all the lists. In this case, the new list, say `mylist` should contain `"123"`and `"126"`. How can do this in R?

Comment: those are vectors not lists, you might be looking for the function `grep`

Comment: `Reduce(intersect, list(list1,list2,list3))` is what I have been looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Just an FYI, it was the first hit in the search `[r] intersect lists`